# How can i run maven Failed UI Test cases?

Tags: automated-tests, maven-3, ui-automation

I have created a maven UI test project. Now,i run by command as mvn test. But i want to re run failed test cases. Should i have to do something in pom file or by command? Any help, please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven-surefire-plugin + rerunFailingTestsCount parameter. It works with JUnit4+. See example below.
Peace of pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <reportsDirectory> ${project.basedir}/test-output</reportsDirectory>
            <rerunFailingTestsCount>1</rerunFailingTestsCount>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Simple java test:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Random;

public class SimpleTest {
    @Test
    public void test(){
        if(new Random().nextBoolean()) {
            Assert.fail();
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running SimpleTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.025 sec <<< FAILURE! - in SimpleTest
test(SimpleTest)  Time elapsed: 0.008 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError
        at SimpleTest.test(SimpleTest.java:10)


Results :

Flaked tests:
SimpleTest.test(SimpleTest)
  Run 1: SimpleTest.test:10
  Run 2: PASS


Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Flakes: 1

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```